# Cannot open shared GCC library

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, shared-libraries, sublimetext2

This question should be simple for those familiar with GCC. I'm hoping to be soon.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/cc1plus.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm launching this GCC doohickey from Sublime Text 2, directly calling g++-4.exe instead of the g++.exe (which wasn't recognised as a program).
Apparently the recommended fix is to add the folder that contains whatever library is missing to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable using `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=somefolder`. However, no library is being specified, just a '?' in its place.

I'm following instructions to install clang, and I'm using Windows 7 Pro, 64-bit. The code being compiled is a single C++ file.

Cheers...

Comment: How do you invoke the compiler? Fomr within a cygwin terminal or forma windows command prompt?

Comment: I'm running it as a Build command from Sublime Text 2, so I'm guessing it's closer to the latter than the former. The format is essentially: "C:/Users/username.DOMAIN/Desktop/clangy/cygwin/bin/g++-4.exe" "Y:\Projects\GitHub\Lacewing-Relay\example-relay-client.cc" -o "Y:\Projects\GitHub\Lacewing-Relay\example-relay-client"

Comment: If you run g++ directly, then it must be run inside cygwin. If you would invooke it from DOS/Windows it wouldn't work, because in the default installation it is a link which fails under Windows. Did you try to comile manually, maye this gives more info?

Comment: It gives an entirely different set of information, about a missing header file. I'm assuming then I should somehow call g++ through the cygwin console?

Comment: Either that, or you must look why your framework has different paths. I don't know these tools, so I can't say.

Answer (score 1):

Hah, I met the same problem when I am trying to use the g++ of my cygwin as a compiler in sublime. Eventually I found this simple solution: **Insert the following line to C++.sublime-build.**

`"path": "D:/Tools/Cygwin/bin/",`

After this edition, my C++.sublime-build has the following content:

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++","${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++, source.cpp",
    "path": "D:/Tools/Cygwin/bin/",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
        }
    ]
}
```

At least this works for me!

---

**How to find C++.sublime-build?**
Preferences > Browse Packages > C++ > C++.sublime-build

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin applications are built in a shell that renders the Windows files system as a virtual Unix style file system.  In Windows the "C:\" drive maps to /cygdrive/c in cygwin.  I'm not aware of any way to emulate this mapping within a Windows command shell, or any Windows application.

All of the paths embedded in gcc and g++ have references to the path in the virtual file system.  For simple apps with no external dependencies this isn't a problem.  But for g++ and others they must be run from a Cygwin shell.  It might be possible to run 'bash -c g++ ...' from a Windows command, but I don't have access to a setup to try it.